# Detecting or preventing assignment operator to a class

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to make a class can be only initialized at declaration.

```
Public Class AnyValue
    Private value As Int32

    Public Sub New(ByVal aValue As Int32)
        value = aValue
    End Sub
End Class

'I want to be able to do this:
Dim val As New AnyValue(8)

'But not this.
val = New AnyValue(9)
```

Or it is possible to stop the assignment or detect when the operator = is used.

Comment: It's an interesting question. Now, if you're not asking this just out of curiosity, but because you really need it, then please note: whatever is the reason you need it, there's **certainly** other ways to do it. And if it's the latter, may I know what such situation you've encountered in which you need this?

Comment: Since the operator cannot be overloaded, maybe it can be stopped.

Comment: This is feature of the language and not any specific class.

Comment: If you _only_ need a _single_ instance of class `AnyValue`, you could just make it static.

Comment: Jason > I want to use more than one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets just say this - No, you can't do what you want. The closest thing to it that I can think of, is to hide the constructor and give static access to the consumer as follows:

```
Public Class AnyValue
    Private value As Int32

    Private Sub New(ByVal aValue As Int32) ' Note - private constructor
        value = aValue
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Create(ByVal aValue As Int32) As AnyValue
        Return New AnyValue(aValue)
    End Function

End Class

'This will not work
Dim val As New AnyValue(8)

'This will not work
val = New AnyValue(9)

' This will work
Dim val As AnyValue = AnyValue.Create(8)
```

Now, if you look at this method of object creation, you can see that you can set all sort of rules for object construction. So, the client has very little input on the construction itself because how you construct the object is totally controlled by the object itself.

Comment: I found this on another site, but I wanted to check if it was possible.